# CSS 3d Transform (Spin animation) does not rotate fully and continuously

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Essentially, I have a div that is being rotated by a CSS animation. It utilizes the rotateY transformation. I have attached a snippet of the code below. There is obviously other code that contributes to it being functional. Visually, it appears that it spins to one side, then spins back in the other direction. It actually used to spin completely and fluidly in a perfect circular motion, and I am unsure why it ceased to have this behavior.

```css
.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: spinx 10s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes spinx {
  from{
    transform: rotatey(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotatey(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="border" class="square">
  <img src="https://www.simpleimageresizer.com/_uploads/photos/77addf44/placeholder.com-logo3_1_200x100.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your icon is indeed spinning one full circle: the reason why you _think_ it spins 180deg and then backwards is due to the [spinning dancer illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_dancer). Due to the lack of depth information, your brain tricks you into thinking the logo spins 180deg and then backwards again.

Comment: Is there any way to combat this? I noticed that it would look as though it was spinning in a full circle the first time, but then would result in that way. Thank you very much for explaining.

Comment: You need to give it a `perspective`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Comment: I was attempting that, but could not seem to get it to work. I had applied a 400px perspective upon the .square class, but it did not result in a different outcome. Do you recommend a specific perspective?

Comment: It's really up to you to play around with the values: there is no "correct" value per se. There should be examples on the linked MDN docs to guide you. Hint: you should be animating the `<img>` itself, as the parent `<div>` is not "shrink-wrapped" around it, and may lead to 3D effect that you don't intend.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I will modify the ```<img>``` instead.